# Converting a nested JSON array to pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a nested JSON array which I have to convert to dataframe. None of the solutions shared for similar issues worked. But this JSON looks like a hard nut to crack. Please help. I want to retrieve the title and dpoin values (top":82,"left":33,"height":52,"width":675)

```
[
{
   "ID":"rtbg345h",
   "DataRow ID":"dgdfg45654",
   "Labeled Data":"https://abc.png",
   "Label":{
      "objects":[
         {
            "featureId":"rtbg345h",
            "schemaId":"rtbg345h",
            "title":"iris",
            "value":"flower",
            "color":"#00RGAA",
            "dpoin":{
               "top":82,
               "left":33,
               "height":52,
               "width":675
            },
            "instanceURI":"https://sdfdsf.ab"
         }
      ],
      "classifications":[

      ]
   },
   "Created By":"user",
   "Project Name":"myfirstproject",
   "Created At":"2018-02-02",
   "Updated At":"2018-02-02",
   "Seconds to Label":24.264,
   "External ID":"sds.jpg",
   "Agreement":-1,
   "Benchmark Agreement":-1,
   "Benchmark ID":null,
   "Dataset Name":"mine",
   "Reviews":[

   ],
   "View Label":"https:fdrtdf"
}
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse the string as JSON using `json.loads()`:

```
import json

# defining the provided string
dat =  '{"ID":"rtbg345h","DataRow ID":"dgdfg45654","Labeled Data":"https://abc.png","Label":{"objects":[{"featureId":"rtbg345h","schemaId":"rtbg345h","title":"iris","value":"flower","color":"#00RGAA","dpoin":{"top":82,"left":33,"height":52,"width":675},"instanceURI":"https://sdfdsf.ab"}],"classifications":[]},"Created By":"user","Project Name":"myfirstproject","Created At":"2018-02-02","Updated At":"2018-02-02","Seconds to Label":24.264,"External ID":"sds.jpg","Agreement":-1,"Benchmark Agreement":-1,"Benchmark ID":null,"Dataset Name":"mine","Reviews":[],"View Label":"https:fdrtdf"}'

# parsing string as JSON
res = json.loads(dat)
```

Here's what the parsed JSON looks like:

```
{'ID': 'rtbg345h',
 'DataRow ID': 'dgdfg45654',
 'Labeled Data': 'https://abc.png',
 'Label': {'objects': [{'featureId': 'rtbg345h',
    'schemaId': 'rtbg345h',
    'title': 'iris',
    'value': 'flower',
    'color': '#00RGAA',
    'dpoin': {'top': 82, 'left': 33, 'height': 52, 'width': 675},
    'instanceURI': 'https://sdfdsf.ab'}],
  'classifications': []},
 'Created By': 'user',
 'Project Name': 'myfirstproject',
 'Created At': '2018-02-02',
 'Updated At': '2018-02-02',
 'Seconds to Label': 24.264,
 'External ID': 'sds.jpg',
 'Agreement': -1,
 'Benchmark Agreement': -1,
 'Benchmark ID': None,
 'Dataset Name': 'mine',
 'Reviews': [],
 'View Label': 'https:fdrtdf'}
```

Then, access the elements using the appropriate notation (note that `res['Label']['objects']` is a list containing a single dictionary)

```
title = res['Label']['objects'][0]['title']
dpoin = res['Label']['objects'][0]['dpoin']
```

If you have a list of JSON objects, you can parse each one individually, storing the parsed data in a list. Once you've parsed all the JSON objects, you can create a dataframe from the list.

Here's an example that keeps track of the data in a list of dictionaries:

```
l = [dat, dat] # repeating the obj you provided to make an example list

rows = []

for item in l: 
    res = json.loads(item)
    row = res['Label']['objects'][0]['dpoin']
    row['title'] = res['Label']['objects'][0]['title']
    rows.append(row)

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(rows)
df
```

Resulting in this dataframe:

```
   top  left  height  width title
0   82    33      52    675  iris
1   82    33      52    675  iris
```

This example creates a dictionary `row` for each JSON object, contaning all the fields from `dpoin` as well as the `title`. Storing the data as a list of dictionaries allows you to use the `pd.DataFrame.from_dict()` constructor.